# AWS EC2 USERDATA NPM INSTALL

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, installation

I have this user data script in templates to launch ec2 instances:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y

export HOME=/home/ec2-user
nodev='16.19.0'
nvmv='0.39.3'
gitrepo='https://github.com/ptv1p3r/etl-fuel-priceguide-ec2.git'

su - ec2-user -c "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v${nvmv}/install.sh | bash"
su - ec2-user -c "nvm install ${nodev}"
su - ec2-user -c "nvm use ${nodev}"

# install git
yum install git -y

# get repository clone
cd /home/ec2-user
su - ec2-user -c "git clone ${gitrepo}"

# install node modules
cd /home/ec2-user/etl-fuel-priceguide-ec2
su - ec2-user -c "npm install"

# start app
su - ec2-user -c "node index.js"
```

Everything works until I need to do the npm install, instead of npm install run in the git clone folder created it keeps being run on the /home/ec2-user folder and then gives error of not finding the package.json.

I cant git clone into /home/ec2-user folder because its not empty, and I simply cant move to the created git clone folder to run npm install there, please help

Comment: Try sudo -u ec2-user instead of su - ec2-user

Comment: `su -` logs in as that user, placing you in their home directory. You should use `sudo -u` instead of `su -` as suggested above.

Comment: @Riz, done :-) ty both for pointing me in the right way, it is working but with a mix of su and sudo a even nothing because of ownership of every folder, mas now its ok, and the sudo -u ec2-user was the way to go.